# HashTable in WebService gives "type unsupported" error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, hashtable

I try to use a HashTable in my webservice.Some of my webservice method prepare some data and add them to the HashTable, then return it to the client.So when i run my webservice is gives this error:

`The type system.collections.hashtable is not supported because it implements IDictionary.`

What is the problem? I can use HashTable in webservice, can't I?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? It wouldn't solve your problem, but you should no longer be using `HashTable` unless you're using .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a hashtable from a Web Service because it can't be serialized.

Can you convert your data to a simple list or array before you return it?

Or:  http://tiwaripradeep.blogspot.com/2007/06/type-systemcollectionshashtable-is-not.html